Consulta a BD 3 últimos de cada registro duplicado
Buen día, no sabía como formular la pregunta pero tratare de expliarles para ver si me doy a entender, necesito consultar una tabla donde varios valores se repiten pero solo necesito consultar los últimos 3 de cada uno, agrego foto de ejemplo y un código que creo yo funcionaría.

El código de la consulta necesito que cada que se agreguen nuevos registros me los muestre (los 3 últimos) o los que estan en el recuadro verde


<?php


SELECT id,numero, estado
FROM tabla
GROUP BY numero, estado ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3;


?>



Creo me estoy equivocando y el LIMIT 3 solo me mostrará 3 registros en la tabla y no 3 de cada uno.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! si.. limit 3 solo te mostrara los ultimos 3.. asi que como usas limit podemos suponer que usas mysql??? eso es importante, porque la solucion varia segun la db que estes usando...

como haces para determinar/diferenciar cuales son los 3 ultimos registro en la tabla???

Primero, debes agregar a tu tabla una columna que permita diferenciar en general cuáles son los registros más recientes, ya sea de toda la tabla o de cada registro 'numero' diferente. Para esto puedes usar una columna 'id'. Si la tabla se llama 'data', entonces:
ALTER TABLE data ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

Ahora puedes aplicar la siguiente consulta:
SELECT numero, estado
FROM (
    SELECT numero, estado,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY numero ORDER BY id DESC) as rn
    FROM data
) subquery
WHERE rn <= 3;

Te devolverá los tres registros más recientes agregados para cada uno de los diferentes valores de 'numero'. Usando tus datos de muestra, te devolverá algo así:
numero  |   estado
------- | ----------    
44445   |   02-10
44445   |   03-10
44445   |   04-10
123456  |   06-10
123456  |   07-10
123456  |   08-10

